# Symbol for proportional inequality

Tags: analysis

Is there a symbol to show that a set of proportional relations are upper bounded by a certain relation.

To give you an example of what I mean.

Assum, I know that a constant $c$ is either proportional to the function $\rho(\Omega)$ or $h(\Omega)$, however, I know, that it is always upper-bounded by the proportional relation $c \propto Vol(\Omega)$

Is there a symbol to express "upper-bounded proportionality" directly?

Something along the line of
$c$~$<Vol(\Omega)$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I'm not sure I understand your question, but check out [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)

Comment: You assume to know that $c\propto \rho(\Omega)$ and $c\propto 2\rho(\Omega)$, but this is the same thing. The statement $c\propto \rho(\Omega)$ means $c=A\rho(\Omega)$ where $A$ is some constant. I think it is common place to just write two statements: $C\propto \rho(\Omega)$,  $\quad C<\text{Vol}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I adjusted the example. I think that the big O notation should work in my case. I was just wondering if there is an explicit symbol to express this relation.